# The object's orange point disappeared in the edit mode, when I use the key tab ( blender : coffee cup level 3 part 2 )

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, selection-tools

[image: tea cup screenshot, no origin visible]

I don't know why after using the tab key
the coffee cup's orange point has disappeared.
Did I lock something or missed something?

Could you mind teach me to solve the problem?
Your are my superhero! Thank You!

Comment: you mean vertices by "orange point"? If yes use "1" key to come back to vertex selection mode.

Comment: yes!yes!yes!!!Thank you!!!!!!!Thank you!!!!!!!Your are my superhero !

Comment: lol, I did well to come...

Comment: ❤️❤️❤️you saved me!!!!!